# How to check if a memory mapped file is exist?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, ipc, memory-mapped-files

I need a way to check if some MMF (Memory mapped file) is exists or not before accessing it, in a managed way.

Comment: Why not a real question?

Comment: `File.Exists` won't do the trick? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Comment: To use Raymond Chen words: "if you need to know then you are doing it wrong".  You'll discover this once you make sure that only one process can access the mmf at the same time.  And you do something meaningful when one of the processes terminates unexpectedly.

Comment: And what do you want to do if it doesn't exist? Create it?

Comment: @HansPassant I disagree. There are plenty of applications that might want to read from a memory mapped file at the same time, otherwise what is the point of shared memory? What if an application wants to read from shared memory, but only if it exists, otherwise it will get its data from another source?

Comment: This is entirely a valid question.  You can use a number of approaches to ensure that only one process can handle a memory mapped file at a time.  You still may want to check to see if another process has created a MMF before trying to call OpenExisting, and instead maybe returning early to prevent unnecessary code execution.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Closing this as "not a real question" is ridiculous.

Comment: This is a reasonable questions and has been provided a reasonable answer. It should not be closed.

Answer (score 8):

You can use : [MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267590%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method. It raises [FileNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.filenotfoundexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in case if specified file is not present.

Comment: Can I do it without exception? it is not a good practice at all!

Comment: @MohamedSakherSawan: there is no any method, at least known to me, that let you do what you want. But this is  not a problem at all, as managing program flow with exceptions is a *very common*, if not often *only possible* way to manage IO access in program.

Comment: But it is very bad for performance! you may be right for IO.